# accented character takes one more char

Tags: java, database, oracle, character-encoding

I have the following problem:

I have to store in the database the data that is inserted in an input field inside a form. I validate that the data in that input doesn't exceed 40 chars.

The problem is, if I insert a text that has 40 characters but one of them is accented, then obviously the validation doesn't show any errors but when it's going to be stored in the database then the following exception is thrown:

ORA-12899: value too large for column "DBUSER"."TABLE"."COLUMN" (actual: 41, maximum: 40)

it seems that the accented character takes up more than one char in the database.

i guess this has to do with the encoding but i have no idea where to start looking. any ideas?

thanks!!

Comment: What is character encoding of your database?

Comment: the parameter NLS_CHARACTERSET is set to AL32UTF8

Comment: Can you publish the code that you use to validate the input, plus can you give a example of problem characters.

Comment: UTF-8 is Unicode.  There are valid unicode characters that require multiple bytes to encode.  It appears that you have found one.

Comment: The oracle column is 40 bytes long, not 40 characters long.  If a string requires 41 bytes to encode 40 characters, then it will be too long to fit.

Comment: What's the reason you have a 40-character restriction?

Comment: @DwB: Unless you declare the column as varchar2(40 char).

Comment: the business logic requires that the string can't have more than 40 chars. my mistake here was that i didn't know how strings were stored in a varchar2 type of field. but thanks everyone for your comments and answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Use `NVARCHAR2` as type](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/NVARCHAR2) for the column or make the column at least six times as wide as the longest input (one Unicode character can become at most 6 bytes with the UTF-8 encoding).

Comment: NVARCHAR2 is definitely the way to go. Of course, switching data types like this is not a simple process. The problem originates in poor design: choosing a unicode characterset without building a data model which supports it. This would be a good time to point to *that article* by Joel Spolsky, patron saint of SO: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: FWIW, the approach i've taken in the past is to budget for a certain proportion of non-ASCII characters. If you're building a site that will handle a range of European languages, then you probably need to allow something like 10% of the characters to be accented (in an article off the front page of Le Monde, i just measured it at 3.4%; 10% has plenty of headroom). So, if you have a 40-character field, allow it to be 44 bytes.

Comment: Although to be honest, given the way that Oracle, and other modern databases, store strings, i'd probably just declare every (n)varchar column as being 4000 characters long, and do all validation in the application layer.

Answer (score 3):

Use `CHAR`, as @Adam Musch suggested.  You really don't want to use NVARCHAR2, or guess at the possible number of bytes.

```
create table my_table1(small_string varchar2(1 byte));
create table my_table2(small_string varchar2(1 char));

insert into my_table1 values('Þ'); --"ORA-12899: value too large for ..."
insert into my_table2 values('Þ'); --works fine
```

---

You can explicitly set the length semantics to either BYTE or CHAR, but most likely you're using the default value, BYTE.  The default is determined by [NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17110/initparams149.htm#CHDFHDJI).  Check the value with this query:

```
select * from v$parameter where name = 'nls_length_semantics';
```

You can change the default with the below statement.  (Although you'll probably forget to change this parameter, it's more reliable to explicitly
use `CHAR` in your DDL.)

```
alter session set nls_length_semantics = char;
```

That setting doesn't change existing objects, you'll need to manually change your table with SQL like:

```
alter table my_table1 modify (small_string varchar2(1 char));
```